# How to combine few row record in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, stored-procedures

I am trying to combine few rows combine and output as 1 row. Here is my example and my expected output. I have tried group_concat and put if/ case condition in query but it seems somehow cannot output as I expected. Thanks in advance.

```
Data:
id | Type   | Name       |Supermarket
1    Fruit    Apple       East
2    Fruit    Orange      West
3    Fruit    Pear        Central

Expected Output:
Type   |East    |West      |Central
Fruit   Apple    Orange     Pear
```

Comment: You say you've made some efforts but they didn't work out. You should add them to your question as this will help us see how you think about the problem and make us more effective at explaining what you need to do to learn how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicate questions I looked up for this didn't have very clear answers IMHO, so I'll write one:

First we need to spread the data we are interested in across 3 columns:

```
SELECT
  type,
  CASE WHEN supermarket = 'east' THEN name END as east,
  CASE WHEN supermarket = 'west' THEN name END as west,
  CASE WHEN supermarket = 'central' THEN name END as central
FROM t
```

Run that and you'll see the data spread out to 3 rows and 3 columns, mostly nulls. Now we need to get rid of the nulls. If we use MAX() on every column with nulls we will hide everything except the one cell that has a value (max will always pick a value over null)

```
SELECT
  type,
  MAX(CASE WHEN supermarket = 'east' THEN name END) as east,
  MAX(CASE WHEN supermarket = 'west' THEN name END) as west,
  MAX(CASE WHEN supermarket = 'central' THEN name END) as central
FROM t
GROUP BY type
```